# How to check in one method if the data NULL for Object JSON and Stream

Tags: c#, generics

I have two methods ImportJson and ImportStream

- The method ImportJson with DataImportJsonObject  as input parameter  (DataImportJsonObject   is an object)

```
public void ImportJSON(DataImportJsonObject request)
{ 
    if (request == null)
    { 
        string messageResult = "EmptyData";
    }        
}
```

- The method ImportStream with stream as input parameter :

```
public void ImportStream(Stream request)
{ 
    if (request.Length < 0)
    { 
        string messageResult = "EmptyData";
    }             
}
```

In fact, with these two methods I want to chack if the enter data is null or not ,
I want to create just one method to check in the same time: if the input is Stream or an object ,

I try with a generic method, but I have a problem with the Stream to check it with Length,

```
   public  class MyGenericClass<T>
    {
        private T genericMemberVariable;

        public MyGenericClass(T value)
        {
            genericMemberVariable = value;
        }
        public T genericMethod(T genericParameter)
        {

            if (genericParameter == null) 
            {
                   //...
            }
            if (genericParameter is Stream)
            {
                genericParameter.Length // It is not possible this treatment
            }

            return genericMemberVariable;
        }
    }
```

How can I code this try ? Or if exist other advice or suggestion  to achieve my objectif ?
Thanks,

Comment: why don't you simply cast it: `(genericParameter as Stream).Length`

Comment: And why you wana make one method? it will be hard to maintain such code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access `.Length`, you would need to cast.

This can be done cleanly using pattern matching:

```
if (genericParameter is Stream stream)
{
    stream.Length // now ok
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use casting:

```
if (genericParameter is Stream)
{
    var length = (genericParameter as Stream).Length;
}
```

Comment: He wants the method to be used for types other than `Stream`.

Comment: `(genericParameter as Stream)?` no need to use null operator there, your if checks this.

Comment: @StepUp welcome, I would rather mention this, than to let it go by :)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ yeah, it is important notice! I like it! Great! Thanks!  :)